# Oracle APEX gives error 'NO DATA FOUND' when trying to fetch value of disabled field of tabular form

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I am trying to update a table using update query from oracle apex process. For that I needed a value to be fetch from a tabular form. But that feild is currently disabled (Not editable, value still exist), and here I'm getting error 'ORA-01403: no data found'. If I enabled that field then problem goes (But field will be editable, I don't want to make that field editable).

That data (data of disabled) is already being saved on table(before that field getting disabled). Now I've written a condition for bypassing that error (like. IF APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(i) IS NOT NULL THEN). But still I'm getting this same error (mentioned above).

So as per shown in below code 'coz of apex_application.g_f03(i) is disabled it gives me error 'ORA-01403: no data found', whereas apex_application.g_f04(i) is not giving me any error. and if I enabled apex_application.g_f03(i) field, then error will be gone.

```
FOR i IN 1 ..apex_application.g_f01.count LOOP   

        if ((:P2_M1= 'f03') AND (apex_application.g_f03(i) IS NOT NULL)) then 
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            select  count(*) into v_count from SCHEMA1.TABLE1 
            where   ATTRIBUTE_CODE  =   apex_application.g_f02(i)   
            and     header_id       =   :P2_X_HEADER_ID
            and     rating_001 is not null ;
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            update  SCHEMA1.TABLE1 
            set     LAST_UPDATE_DATE =  sysdate,
                    LAST_UPDATED_BY  =  :F2221_USER_ID,
                    RATING_001       =  apex_application.g_f03(i),
                    STATUS           =  'NEW' 
            where   ATTRIBUTE_CODE  =   apex_application.g_f02(i)
            and     header_id       =   :P2_X_HEADER_ID;
            --------------------------------------------------------------
        END IF;  

        if ((:P2_M2 = 'f04') AND (apex_application.g_f04(i) IS NOT NULL)) then

            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            select count(*) into v_count from SCHEMA1.TABLE1 
            where  ATTRIBUTE_CODE   =   apex_application.g_f02(i)   
            and    header_id        =   :P2_X_HEADER_ID
            and    rating_002 is not null ;    
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            update  SCHEMA1.TABLE1 
            set     LAST_UPDATE_DATE=   sysdate,
                    LAST_UPDATED_BY =   :F2221_USER_ID,
                    RATING_002      =   apex_application.g_f04(i),
                    STATUS          =   'NEW' 
            where   ATTRIBUTE_CODE  =   apex_application.g_f02(i)   
            and     header_id       =   :P2_X_HEADER_ID;
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        END IF; 

    end loop;
```

I expected either to get the value of this apex_application.g_f03(i) field (even if it is disabled) or bypass it.

Comment: have you tried using the exists operator..?? may be like apex_application.g_f03.exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behaviour of any HTML form, not just APEX.  If any input is set to **disabled** then its value is not posted when the form is submitted.  If you can set it to **readonly** instead then the user will still be unable to edit it, but its value will be posted on submit.